# AWS Lambda stops working if it breaks once

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda with 5s timeout. Here is a simple lambda that I upload:

```
exports.handle = function(event, context, callback) {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        callback(null, "done");
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => callback(null, "delayed"), 6000);
    }
};
```

As you can see, 50% of the times it should just return `'done'` but the other 50% of the time, there should be a delay that is higher than the timeout and I expect to get a timeout error.

Problem is, once I get the timeout error, I will ALWAYS get a timeout error. The lambda stops working.

How come? I even tried `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` without any success

Comment: You have any related log/console output from Lambda?

Comment: Nothing useful; just the typical `Task timed out after 5.00 seconds` but once this happens, it will ALWAYS happen ...

Comment: Does it stop working after the first timeout? Are you sure your handler is `exports.handle` and not `exports.handler`. I tested your lambda function and it is working fine.

Comment: Add logging. Log something, anything, as the first thing you do inside the handler, and the first thing in each conditional branch.  You say it will ALWAYS happen... but exactly **what** will always happen?  You don't know what your code is doing without some logging.

Comment: A coworker and I are running into the same problem, and even a print statement (we're using Python) on the first line of the handler isn't getting called.  We're just getting an immediate timeout that says it's been 10 seconds.  Would it be a problem with the context it's receiving?

Comment: If anyone cares, that coworker discovered that if he increased the timeout he could intentionally timeout the Lambda but it would recover (I guess it just takes a ridiculously long time to recover from timing out on a previous instance or something strange).