# AWS Lambda "errorMessage": Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, image-resizing

Lambda function showing the below error in test when changing file format from `png` to `text`

```
"errorMessage": "2020-07-17T07:06:45.969Z b66dd037-ba01-4025-97db-6527b486eac8 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
```

Answer (score 172):

I have same error - increasing the timeout resolved it:

In the AWS Management Console:

```
lambda function -> configuration -> General configuration -> Edit Timeout
```

[image]

Answer (score 29):

The default Lambda timeout is 3 seconds.

To resolve this do one of the following:

- Increase the timeout of your Lambda function, it can be [upto 15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/). The recommendation would be to set it to the duration of how long you anticipate it will take.
- Increase the resources (memory/CPU) so that your function is quicker at performing its target action.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue, tried with increasing memory and timeout value too, but not worked.

Problem is with booting the lambda function into the memory. So I moved a bigger dependency inside the functional call. For me its `urllib` dependency.

As Python import dependency works at runtime so booting lambda function worked without any load/lag.

Comment: can you share an example of how you moved the dependency inside the functional call?