# How to use a linear regression model in Lambda using a pkl file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, linear-regression, pickle

I have trained a linear regression model and saved the model in a `pkl` file, with the following code:

```
import pickle

# save the model
filename = 'linear_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(mod, open(filename, 'wb'))
  
# load the model
load_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

After that I tried to use the model in Lambda by importing the `pkl` file. I did a lot of research and many attempts, but could not figure out how to do this. My last attempt was this one:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pickle
import boto3
import base64
import json

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # getting bucket and object key from event object
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    data = BytesIO()
    s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, key, data)
    data.seek(0)    # move back to the beginning after writing
    print("Data", data.read())

    
    load_model = pickle.load(open(data, 'rb'))
    print("load_model", load_model)
    
    y_pred = load_model.predict([[140000]])
```

```
[ERROR] TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in lambda_handler
    load_model = pickle.load(open(data, 'rb'))
```

I tried to fix this error using `data.read()`, but if you do that no file is found in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `data` is a `BytesIO` but you try to `open` it like a file.  You can not do it on `BytesIO`.
- Don't read from stream.
- pickle.load accepts a file. But you have `data` stream. You need to use `loads` function.

Update version of lambda function.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import pickle
import boto3
import base64
import json

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # getting bucket and object key from event object
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    data = BytesIO()
    s3_client.download_fileobj(source_bucket, key, data)
    data.seek(0)    # move back to the beginning after writing
    
    load_model = pickle.loads(data.read())
    print("load_model", load_model)
    
    y_pred = load_model.predict([[140000]])
```

Comment: Hi @Mehmet Güngören I followed your answer, but ended up with another error. `[ERROR] TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler load_model = pickle.loads(data)`.

Comment: Just do this, you will get bytes like object from BytesIO --> `load_model = pickle.loads(data.read())`

Comment: Thanks @Mehmet Güngören. It worked, only the timeout needs to be increased, which is already answered here: [Edit Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948910/aws-lambda-errormessage-task-timed-out-after-3-00-seconds).